# Metadata regarding AWS EIP Alloacation Date and Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, elastic-ip

Can't find and answer to my question on the internet, AWS, or here. I am trying to find metadata on EIP allocation date from AWS's pool (or at least the last associated date). So I can delete EIP's older than 4 wks that are not associated with resources.

Am I missing something obvious? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am able to obtain this information via cloudtrail, but I am curious as to how it could be done if my client is not using cloudtrail.

Comment: This info can be obtained via cloudtrail, but it just dawned on me that cloudtrail records are only kept for 90 days by default.